# Mocking a method inside another method

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, mocking, mockito

This is the method i'm testing and i'm using mockito for mocking:

```
 /**
     * Sync get all children under single zk node.
     *
     * @param zk
     *          zookeeper client
     * @param node
     *          node path
     * @return direct children
     * @throws InterruptedException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static List<String> getChildrenInSingleNode(final ZooKeeper zk, final String node, long zkOpTimeoutMs)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException, KeeperException.NoNodeException {
        final GetChildrenCtx ctx = new GetChildrenCtx();
        getChildrenInSingleNode(zk, node, new GenericCallback<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(int rc, List<String> ledgers) {
                synchronized (ctx) {
                    if (Code.OK.intValue() == rc) {
                        ctx.children = ledgers;
                    }
                    ctx.rc = rc;
                    ctx.done = true;
                    ctx.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        });

        synchronized (ctx) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (!ctx.done) {
                try {
                    ctx.wait(zkOpTimeoutMs > 0 ? zkOpTimeoutMs : 0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    ctx.rc = Code.OPERATIONTIMEOUT.intValue();
                    ctx.done = true;
                }
                // timeout the process if get-children response not received
                // zkOpTimeoutMs.
                if (zkOpTimeoutMs > 0 && (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) >= zkOpTimeoutMs) {
                    ctx.rc = Code.OPERATIONTIMEOUT.intValue();
                    ctx.done = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Code.NONODE.intValue() == ctx.rc) {
            throw new KeeperException.NoNodeException("Got NoNode on call to getChildren on path " + node);
        } else if (Code.OK.intValue() != ctx.rc) {
            throw new IOException("Error on getting children from node " + node);
        }
        return ctx.children;
    }
```

And this is my test class:

```
@RunWith(value= Parameterized.class)

public class ZkUtilsGetChildrenTest  {


    private boolean expectedResult;
    private ZooKeeper zkc ;
    private String path;
    private long timeout;
    private static List<String> paths = Arrays.asList("/ledgers/000/000/000/001", "/ledgers/000/000/000/002",
            "/ledgers/000/000/000/003");
    private static List<String> childPaths = Arrays.asList("001", "002", "003");
    // ZooKeeper related variables
    private static ZooKeeperUtil zkUtil = new ZooKeeperUtil();

    @Mock
    ZkUtils.GetChildrenCtx mocked = mock(ZkUtils.GetChildrenCtx.class) ;


    @BeforeClass
    public static  void setUp() throws Exception {

        zkUtil.startCluster();
        ZooKeeper initializerZkc = new ZooKeeper(zkUtil.getZooKeeperConnectString(), 10000, null);

        for (String path : paths ){

            ZkUtils.createFullPathOptimistic(initializerZkc, path, "data".getBytes() , ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE ,
                    CreateMode.CONTAINER);

        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {

        zkUtil.killCluster();

    }


    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getTestParameters() throws IOException {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{


                {false , "null" , "/ledgers/000/000/000/004" , 0},

                {true , "new" , "/ledgers/000/000/000" , 1000 },

                {false , "wrong" , "/ledgers/000/000/000/00b" , -1},

                {false , "new" , "/ledgers/000/000/00b" , 0 },//aggiunto per migliorare statement e branch coverage

                {false , "new" , "/ledgers/000/000/003" , 1 },//aggiunto per migliorare statement e branch coverage

                {false , "mock" , "/ledgers/000/000" , 1000 },//aggiunto per migliorare statement coverage

        });

    }


    public ZkUtilsGetChildrenTest(boolean expectedResult ,String zkc , String path , long timeout) throws IOException {

        if(zkc == "null"){

            this.zkc = null;

        }else if( zkc == "wrong"){

            this.zkc = new ZooKeeper("wrongString", 10000, null);

        }else if(zkc == "new"){

            this.zkc = new ZooKeeper(zkUtil.getZooKeeperConnectString(), 10000, null);

        }else if(zkc == "mock"){

            //TODO MOCK THE INNER METHOD
            this.zkc = new ZooKeeper(zkUtil.getZooKeeperConnectString(), 10000, null);
            when(mocked).thenThrow(new InterruptedException());
        }

        this.expectedResult = expectedResult;
        this.path = path;
        this.timeout = timeout;


    }

    @Test
    public void testGetChildrenInSingleNode() {

        boolean realResult;

        try {


            List<String> children = ZkUtils.getChildrenInSingleNode(zkc, path, timeout);

            assertThat(children, is(childPaths));



        } catch (Exception e) {

            realResult = false;
            e.printStackTrace();

            assertEquals(expectedResult, realResult);
        }



    }

 }
```

I would like to ask you how can i mock the method ctx.wait(zkOpTimeoutMs > 0 ? zkOpTimeoutMs : 0); so that i can trigger the catch block which follows this statement : if i called this method i would have mocked an istance of this class and call the method on that mock but since is not me who calls this method but it's called by the method under test, how can i properly mock it?

Good day to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Powermock to [mock the creation of new objects](https://automationrhapsody.com/mock-new-object-creation-powermock/) if that is something available to you and you cannot or do not want to refactor the existing code. Using Powermock is not without its own downsides, but is a powerful way to gain more granular control over this and other cases (static class/methods and private/protected classes/methods/fields).

Comment: Asap i try and post updates! But if possible i would prefer a mockito implementation since i read that mockito and powermock lybraries could be conflictual.

Comment: I've used them together without issue, but in the past have had issues with code coverage due to Powermock's presence. But Powermock and Mockito should go hand-in-hand. They can use some of the same method names, so just be sure you're using the right package name. If you do run into any conflicts, I'd definitely be interested to hear of it and maybe we can work through those as well!

Comment: Update: i have tried to follow the guide you linked but my problem it's a bit different man... Usually you are able to mock an object instance of a class and work with that object : my problem is that the object it's not created by me but it's created by the method i am testing so i would need to mock the method call ctx.wait(zkOpTimeoutMs > 0 ? zkOpTimeoutMs : 0); on any ctx object since i cannot create and pass my own ctx instance.

Comment: No, the idea is that you are mocking up the ```GetChildrenCtx``` object, correct? More specifically, you are mocking the constructor to intercept any call for new ```GetChildrenCtx```. What you want to do is whenever ctx.wait is called (and you can specify whether you want it to trigger on a certain argument or any argument), it should throw an error. Usually that's via ```doThrow```. But Powermock is tricky and takes some work to get right. It also depends if it's a static method, etc.

Comment: So I messed up my last comment, but you can have it return a mock from the constructor interceptor - ```PowerMockito.whenNew(Bar.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockBar);```